how to get google calender event list with owner,summery property by using google service account key
i have google service account access key json i want google calendar event list with all properties i try to fetch i got only public datas i want all properties in google calendar how to achieve this
i try api call by using my service account i received
{
  kind: 'calendar#event',
  etag: '"3424455150124000"',
  id: '72hfhqc9jamv8hnersnpqu43ns',
  status: 'confirmed',
  htmlLink: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NzJoZmhxYzlqYW12OGhuZXJzbnBxdTQzbnMgYXJ1bGt1bWFyQGFtd2hpei5jb20',
  updated: '2024-04-04T10:46:15.062Z',
  start: { dateTime: '2024-04-04T16:30:00+05:30', timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata' },
  end: { dateTime: '2024-04-04T17:30:00+05:30', timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata' },
  visibility: 'private',
  iCalUID: '72hfhqc9jamv8hnersnpqu43ns@google.com'
}

my requirement is
{
    "kind": "calendar#event",
    "etag": "\"3421529884678000\"",
    "id": "16797o6c10rkrd9gmpoo12vgs0",
    "status": "confirmed",
    "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MTY3OTdvNmMxMHJrcmQ5Z21wb28xMnZnczAgYXJ1bGt1bWFyQGFtd2hpei5jb20",
    "created": "2024-03-18T12:29:01.000Z",
    "updated": "2024-03-18T12:29:02.339Z",
    "summary": "Weekly Team Meeting",
    "description": "Weekly team meeting to discuss project status.",
    "creator": {
        "email": "gayathri@amwhiz.com"
    },
    "organizer": {
        "email": "gayathri@amwhiz.com"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2024-03-18T15:45:00+05:30",
        "timeZone": "America/New_York"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2024-03-18T16:15:00+05:30",
        "timeZone": "America/New_York"
    },
    "iCalUID": "16797o6c10rkrd9gmpoo12vgs0@google.com",
    "sequence": 0,
    "attendees": [
        {
            "email": "arulkumar@amwhiz.com",
            "self": true,
            "optional": true,
            "responseStatus": "accepted"
        },
        {
            "email": "nagaraj@amwhiz.com",
            "displayName": "John Doe",
            "responseStatus": "needsAction"
        }
    ],
    "reminders": {
        "useDefault": true
    },
    "eventType": "default"
}

how to get all this properties
